# RESTful service contract

Tags: java, rest, wsdl

like WSDL what is the contract for RESTful service it exposes to client. Are there any java frameworks to create the client automatically for consuming RESTful Services ?

Answer (score 3):

In REST your media types and your link relations are your contracts.  It is possible you use [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) as a runtime discovery mechanism, but it is far less flexible than using hypermedia based representations.

REST systems should never use something like WADL to generate client proxy classes.

Answer (score 2):

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is probably the most popular REST library for Java on the server.  They also have client libraries that allow you to consume RESTful services with [an example](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-apache-client/com/sun/jersey/client/apache/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

The RESTful equilivant of a WSDL is a [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)

Answer (score 0):

REST services use what's called "uniform contract" or "uniform interface", which is based on http verbs. Thus, the contract of a REST service is a combination of the uniform interface and the URIs it support. 
To call a SOAP service we pick an operation and the address specified in the concrete section of that services's WSDL definition.
To call a REST service we pick an http verb and a URI.